# Sub string manipulation using CSE or array formula

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, array-formulas

Is there a CSE Array formula that will give me this output?

**Input String** - "Apple" Fruit=Y, "Mango" Fruit=Y, "Aubergine" Fruit = N, "Carrot" Fruit = N,"Coconut" Fruit = Y

**Output String** - Apple, Mango, Coconut

Basically, I want the string enclosed in the quotes where Fruit = Y

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Answer (score 3):

Just another way of doing things:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(following::*[1],', ','')='Fruit=Y']"))
```

Should work with Excel 2019 too when CSE-entered.

---

For older versions of Excel, I'm sure there is a wide variety of approaches. I like to use regular expressions. For example:

```
Function GetFruits(s As String) As String

Static RE As Object: If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = """([^""]+)""\s*Fruit\s*=\s*Y\s*(,)?|."
RE.Global = True
GetFruits = Application.Trim(RE.Replace(s, "$1$2 "))

End Function
```

Call using `=GetFruits(A1)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you tidy up your input string so that it is more consistent, for example comprising consistently "=Y" and not a mixture of "=Y" and " =Y", and separated everywhere by ", " and not sometimes by ",":

```
=LET(
    ζ,TEXTSPLIT(A1," Fruit=",", "),
    TEXTJOIN(", ",,SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(TAKE(ζ,,1),TAKE(ζ,,-1)="Y"),"""",""))
)
```

Comment: You could try to add multiple types of input as an array in `TEXTSPLIT()`. I was also puzzling a bit and saw I got something very similar: `=LET(x,WRAPROWS(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{",",", "},"""",1),2),TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(TAKE(x,,1),RIGHT(DROP(x,,1))="Y","")))`

Comment: @JvdV Ah, yes, using `WRAPROWS` is a nice alternative technique here.

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be done, using a VBA procedure or function:

```
Sub test()
  Dim S As String
  Dim result As String
  
  S = Range("A1").Value
  
  For Each s1 In Split(S, ",")
    If s1 Like "*Fruit=Y" Then
      result = result + " " + s1
    End If
  Next s1
  
  Range("B1").Value = result
End Sub
```

Comment: Just an headsup, but are you sure this produces the result OP is looking for? When I attempt this, it's both missing 'Coconut' *and* it will include much more text then OP is looking for.

Comment: @JvdV: indeed: the question contains some errors, like "Fruit=Y" with and without spaces, and there is no effort from the question author. So I decided not to give a clear and complete answer :-) (but it gives a good idea how to start)